# How to declare Python constraint on generic type to support __lt__?

Tags: python-3.x, generics, types

In the Python 3.5 code below, I want to use a less than operator (`<`) to compare two generic values. How can I declare a constraint on T to support `__lt__`?

```
from typing import *
import operator 

T = TypeVar('T')

class MyList(Generic[T]):
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, k:T) -> None:
            self.key = k 
            self.next = None  # type: Optional[MyList.Node]

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.root = None # type: Optional[MyList.Node]

    def this_works(self, val:T) -> bool:
        return self.root.key == val 

    def not_works(self, val:T) -> bool:
        return operator.lt(self.root.key, val)
```

I'm using [Mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) to type check and it's failing on `not_works` with the message:

```
$ mypy test.py
test.py: note: In member "not_works" of class "MyList":
test.py:20: error: Unsupported left operand type for < ("T")
```

Other languages support constraints on T.

In C#: `class MyList<T> where T:IComparable<T>`

In Java: `class MyList<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Comment: Why do people feel the urge to static type a dynamic language? BTW, why don't you try to define `__ge__` first (`__ge__` is the right side version of `__lt__`). "this_works" works because `__eq__` is defined for all classes .

Comment: @JBernardo “Why do people feel the urge to static type a dynamic language?” — Because there are tons of advantages to it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by passing an extra parameter `bound` to `TypeVar`, as described in [PEP484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-variables-with-an-upper-bound):

> A type variable may specify an upper bound using `bound=<type>`. This means that an actual type substituted (explicitly or implicitly) for the type variable must be a subtype of the boundary type. A common example is the definition of a Comparable type that works well enough to catch the most common errors:

Sample code from mentioned PEP:

```
from typing import TypeVar

class Comparable(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def __lt__(self, other: Any) -> bool: ...
    ... # __gt__ etc. as well

CT = TypeVar('CT', bound=Comparable)

def min(x: CT, y: CT) -> CT:
    if x < y:
        return x
    else:
        return y

min(1, 2) # ok, return type int
min('x', 'y') # ok, return type str
```

In latest version (verified with 0.521) of mypy, the scenario above is correctly handled.

Comment: FWIW this does not typecheck with mypy 0.470: `error: Type argument 1 of "min" has incompatible value "int" `

Comment: Hmm, yep, that's correct. But apart from lack of tooling support this should be way to go (which probably ain't too helpful for OP)

Comment: If you need to use a constructor of the bound class for any reason, you can but you need the prototype to be min(x: Type[CT], y: Type[CT]) -> CT by doing that, you can to x(whatever, the, contstructor, parameters, are)